# Backtrader, using mongodb as datafeed instead CSV

Tags: python, mongodb, backtrader

I'm quite new to backtrader and since I've started I couldn't stop wondering why there's no database support for the datafeed. I've found a page on the official website where's described how to implement a custom datafeed. The implementation should be pretty easy, but on github (or more in general on the web) I couldn't fine a single one implementation of a feed with MongoDb. I understand that CSV are easier to manage and so on, but in some cases could require a lot of RAM for storing data all at once in memory. On the other hand, having a db can be "RAM friendly" but will take longer during the backtesting process even if the DB is a documental one. Does anyone have any experience with both of these two approaches? And if yes, there's some code I can take a look at?

Thanks!